# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" when Ckeditor javascript lib loaded inside index.html in Angular2

Tags: angular, import, ckeditor

I am would like to integrate ckeditor without using angular ckeditor component. So I added code to load ckeditor js file inside index.html.
This is project structure.

```
root
  public
    ckeditor
       ckeditor.js
       ...
  client
    index.html
```

This is what I added inside index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

And chrome show this error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <                  ckeditor.js:1
```

I don't think it's because of wrong path.
I tried with wrong path and it shows same error
so When I added this,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/ckeditor/ckeditor_wrong.js"></script>
```

it shows this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <                  ckeditor_wrong.js:1
```

So what is the reason of this? and how to import correctly?
Looking forward to hearing from you soon.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like an error in an HTML tag not typed correctly, but is hard to tell without seeing all the code. Can you put somewhere the content of your files? The error happens when you imported ckeditor? Is this a compiler error or runtime error?